# Displaying multiple graphs on one page using lazy high charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I am currently writing a ruby on rails app and I am using the lazy high charts gem to display some graphs. However, I'm having trouble displaying two graphs on one page. It seems like the latter graph overrides the first one and so the second graph is the only one that's displayed. Both graphs are displayed if put separately. How do I show both graphs on one page?

This is what's on my controller

```
@performance_chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.title(:text => "Team Performance")
  f.xAxis(:categories => @x_axis)

  f.series(:name => @team.name, :yAxis => 0, :data => @performance)
  f.series(:name => "Top Scores for " + @team.division.name.capitalize[0...-1] + " Division", :yAxis => 0, :data => @top_scores)
  f.series(:name => "Averaged Scores for "+ @team.division.name.capitalize[0...-1] + " Division", :yAxis => 0, :data => @average_scores)
  f.yAxis [
    {:title => {:text => "Quiz Scores", :margin => 70} }
  ]
  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"line"})
end 

#bar graph for individual team members 
@member_chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('column') do |f|
  f.title(:text => "Population vs GDP For 5 Big Countries [2009]")
  f.xAxis(:categories => ["United States", "Japan", "China", "Germany", "France"])
  f.series(:name => "GDP in Billions", :yAxis => 0, :data => [14119, 5068, 4985, 3339, 2656])
  f.series(:name => "Population in Millions", :yAxis => 1, :data => [310, 127, 1340, 81, 65])

  f.yAxis [
    {:title => {:text => "GDP in Billions", :margin => 70} },
    {:title => {:text => "Population in Millions"}, :opposite => true},
  ]

  f.legend(:align => 'right', :verticalAlign => 'top', :y => 75, :x => -50, :layout => 'vertical',)
  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"column"})
end
```

this is what's on my view

```
<div = class"row">
    <div class="card">
        <%= high_chart("some_id", @performance_chart) %>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
    <div class="card">
        <%= high_chart("some_id", @member_chart) %> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that the HighChart.new() took in three parameters, one of which is used to create a div tag.

```
 def high_chart(placeholder, object, &block)
  object.html_options.merge!({:id => placeholder})
  object.options[:chart][:renderTo] = placeholder
  high_graph(placeholder, object, &block).concat(content_tag("div", "", object.html_options))
end
```

So all I had to do was change the name of the id of one of the displayed graph that I called from the controller. If not, it finds the div tag with the same id (in my case the first graph that I've created) and replaces the graph previously displayed. To fix the problem, I changed

```
<%= high_chart("some_id", @member_chart) %>
```

to

```
<%= high_chart("some_other_id", @member_chart) %>
```